# Unknown Hp keyboard layout finding difficulty in programming

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have started doing programming and recently bought a used hp laptop i was ok to use it but as i started programming i noticed that my keyboard symbols printed on keyboard are different from what i write on screen (i also attached a image of my keyboard). I tried changing many keyboard layout but still could not find correct which matches with my keyboard. what can be the solution?[Hp 850 G5 keyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFLB1.jpg)

i tried many keyboard layout but still could not find the correct layout which matches with my keyboard. please see the image i attached and if you identify the keyboard layout please let me know. You can also suggest any solution of it so i can do programming thanks.

Comment: That looks like QWERTY with French AZERTY-like accents.

Comment: A [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/KeyboardLayouts/comments/10l6ngl/what_kind_of_french_qwerty_keyboard_layout_is_this/) suggests this is likely the result of someone taking an AZERTY French keyboard and swapping the key caps to QWERTY. You can 'unfix' it back but then you will have an AZERTY keyboard...